# Only the top 1/3 of the image (approximately) shows in the panel (SimplePanel),

Tags: java, image, gwt

I'm attempting to display a ~80K jpeg image in a GWT panel. (fwiw - the image is retrieved from a database table)

For some reason, only the top 1/3 (approximately) shows in the panel (SimplePanel), when I attempt the display.  Lesser resolution images show in their entirety.  --This issue does not appear to be a function of panel height/width settings.

Would this due to the **32k limit** I've heard about regarding the **IE** brower?

If so, is there a full example of an alternate technique that I could use to display the image (in the SimplePanel) -- i.e., so that the entire image will display in IE?

1. Java 1.6
2. GWT 2.2
3. IE 8

***(snippet of code involved)***

```
-
-
-
//prepare image url on server (for use by client)
String base64Url = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray);
-
-
-
//client retrieving image url (from server)...
AsyncCallback<String> asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
    {
        Window.alert("DetailView/setRowData/asyncCallBack/onFailure - " + caught.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String base64Url)
    {
        Window.alert("DetailView/setRowData/asyncCallBack/onSuccess - base64Url:" + String.valueOf(base64Url));
        imagePanel.clear();
        imagePanel.add(new Image(base64Url));
    }
};
searchValueMap.put("doc_id",doc_id.trim().toUpperCase());
service.getBase64ImageUrl(base64Url, asyncCallback);
-
-
-
```

Comment: FYI - In FireFox(v4) the entire image displays, as it should.  I need this to work in IE8... -- Is there a workaround for this issue?  Thanks again! sd

Answer (score 0):

RFC 2397 hints that its the URL length that is the limiting factor without specifying any particular length:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt

My experience with this is only through the GWT ResourceBundle code.  There, data urls are restricted to only a few browser types, and any image larger than 32K is not eligible to be sent through a data url:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/rebind/context/InlineResourceContext.java?